# Running a javascript on a specific page

Tags: javascript, wordpress

For some reason a js isn't running on a page on my wordpress development site called 'information'. The page template was copied from a page which successfully runs the script so I'm not sure what's missing. I've tried to remedy the situation by running this script in the functions.php file:

```
    function my_scripts() {
            if( is_page( array( 'information') ) ){
                wp_enqueue_script( 'variable_fonts', 'js/variable_fonts.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
            }
        }
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts' );
```

I've also tried running this script on the page itself:

```
<script>
if(location.pathname=="/information/") 
 script.src = /js/variable_fonts.js;
</script>
```

Neither option is working. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to call the function. Just add
`my_scripts()` to the end of your file

Comment: Sorry, I didn't copy the whole code in for the first option, that's corrected now

Answer (score 0):

So with a bit more digging I realised I'd forgot to close the page after chopping out the get footer and get sidebar stuff from the bottom of the page, which was causing the scripts not to load. All fixed now by adding:

```
<?php wp_footer(); ?>

</body>
</html>
```